# Questions regarding Joomla and VirtueMart

Tags: api, joomla, payment, virtuemart, gateway

I need to create an e-commerce website. I am thinking if I can use Joomla and VirtueMart to finish it. I have never used VirtueMart before. I am just worrying about if this solution is great. VirtueMart is a shopping cart… is it easy to link it with payment gateway from different banks? Is it secure? Thank you for any suggestions. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart is probably one of the biggest shopping carts available for Joomla.  It's one of the most comprehensive to my knowledge and I believe that it will accept payment gateway from different banks.  How easy that is to setup is a subjective question... it would depend on your level of comfort with those things.  In my experience Virtuemart is very full figured, secure and is a great ecommerce platform.  Since they've released it for 1.7 it *should* in theory work with 2.5 (the LTS release).  Their support has always been highly reviewed and the user community is large as well.

I've used it before in the past with great success but the sites were much more simple and didn't include working with multiple banks - just paypal support.

Anyhow, I hope this information helps!